# Visual Studio says "Could not find file 'D:\ProjectName.deps.json'." on the drive I run my program from

Tags: c#, json, file

I'm trying to create a program that runs through all the drives on a pc and lists the files.
I have 9 drives in my pc and the program runs fine and lists files on all of them except on the drive from which I'm running the program from. (Doesn't matter which drive.)

I have a recursive function that takes all the files and directories it finds and compiles a list.

The function runs fine on all other drives but for the one from which I'm running the program from it says `Could not find file 'D:\CreateFileList.deps.json'.` and then crashes into catch() for that drive.

Here's the part of the code that does that.

```
static void DirSearch(string sDir, string file)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get files from root of the drive
                if ( firstPass == 1 )
                {
                    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir))
                    {
                        if (CheckExclusion(f))
                        {
                            WriteToFile(f, file);
                        }
                    }
                    firstPass = 0;
                }
                
                // Get files recursively
                foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
                {   
                    if (CheckExclusion(d))
                    {
                        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
                        {
                            if (CheckExclusion(f))
                            {
                                WriteToFile(f, file);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    DirSearch(d, file);
                }
            }

            catch (System.Exception excpt)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
            }
        }
```

Obviously this file is not at the root of the drive but in the same directory as the .exe file.

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong? Do I have some settings wrong or includes or what?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the actual exception being returned. It will give you a hint as to what is happening.

For example if the OS is throwing `UnauthorizedAccessException` your process is not running as admin and will **not** be allowed to look at the directory/files.

You need to handle (`catch`) each of the exceptions listed at [Directory.GetDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=net-5.0) in your try catch.

By handling all (or just the most likely) exceptions, you will be able to have a working program.

Comment: "Could not find file 'D:\CreateFileList.deps.json'" is what "Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);" does return.

Comment: And what does the `InnerException.Message` say?

Comment: it says simply just "null"

Comment: Is the file in use when the program runs?